# Shared pointer segmentation faults -- how to properly share a PlanningScene?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

`ps_ptr` is a boost shared pointer to a [PlanningScene](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/planning_scene/include/moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h#L87) instance, created w/ `boost::make_shared`. The PlanningScene class is declared as,

```
class PlanningScene : private boost::noncopyable, public std::enable_shared_from_this<PlanningScene>
```

and includes a method [`clone`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/planning_scene/src/planning_scene.cpp#L228) for "copying" a planning scene.

These definitions imply to me there is a specific way this class is  intended to be shared. What is the proper way to pass around `ps_ptr`? I would like to share it with another class `SceneStuff`, where `SceneStuff` only uses it to call a const method ([PlanningScene::checkCollision](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/planning_scene/include/moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h#L389)).

Some notes:

- Using `ps_ptr` as-is results in seg-faults due to `double free or corruption`. That's the compiler telling me I'm trying to free memory that has already been freed or was dereferenced, but shouldn't a `boost::shared_ptr` handle this? I've been through many SO threads on this topic, but to no avail.
- I'm unable to call `auto new_ps_ptr = ps_ptr->clone(ps_ptr);` because `no matching function for call to ‘planning_scene::PlanningScene::clone(boost::shared_ptr<planning_scene::PlanningScene>&)’`
- [boost smart pointers docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html)

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Igor's comment I've switched `ps_ptr` to a `std::shared_ptr`, but still get seg-faults occasionally due to the following code (additionally invoked by `SceneStuff`)*C*:

```
// Setup collision-models
auto robot_model_ptr = ps_ptr->getRobotModel();
collision_detection::CollisionRobotFCL crobot(robot_model_ptr);
auto world_ptr = ps_ptr->getWorldNonConst();
collision_detection::CollisionWorldFCL cworld(world_ptr);

// Just standard structs
auto dreq = collision_detection::DistanceRequest();
auto dres = collision_detection::DistanceResult();

// Compute obstacle distances for the given `conf`
moveit::core::RobotState query_state = ps_ptr->getCurrentState();
query_state.setVariablePositions(x.data());  // x is simply an Eigen::VectorXd
cworld.distanceRobot(dreq, dres, crobot, query_state);
```

Here's the relevant source:

- [getRobotModel](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/planning_scene/include/moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h#L141)
- [collision detection fcl package](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/collision_detection_fcl) and specifically [distanceRobot](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/collision_detection_fcl/src/collision_world_fcl.cpp#L272)

**UPDATE 2**: It appears the remaining seg-faults are due to an upstream issue with passing the PlanningScene pointer through Boost Python bindings -- see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202030/segfault-from-passing-a-shared-pointer-between-c-objects-via-boost-python).

Comment: `std::enable_shared_from_this` only works for an instance that's currently managed by `std::shared_ptr`. If you insist on using `boost::shared_ptr`, you would also need to use `boost::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: According to your link, `clone` takes a reference to `planning_scene::PlanningSceneConstPtr`, whatever that might be. Apparently, `ps_ptr` is not of that type. I suspect you are meant to use `std::shared_ptr` after all.

Comment: Good point, thanks @IgorTandetnik! I still have seg-faults though... I'll update the question with details.