# Segfault from passing a shared pointer between C++ objects via Boost Python

Tags: c++, boost-python

I have two custom C++ classes `Foo` and `Baz` that I've successfully exposed to Python via Boost Python; the user interacts with Python classes that run their C++ counterparts under the hood. An important use case is passing a `Foo` Python instance to a Python method `Baz.run_that_foo`. The Python bindings method is,

```
// Note `XPython` is the name for the Boost Python bindings class of `X`.

void BazPython::RunThatFoo(const bp::object & foo) {
    FooPython & foo_obj = bp::extract<FooPython&>(foo);
    auto ps_ptr = foo_obj.GetPSPtr();
    Baz::DoPSComputation(ps_ptr);  // Expects a `const std::shared_ptr<planning_scene::PlanningScene>`
}
```

Importantly, `ps_ptr` is supposed to be a shared pointer to a [PlanningScene](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_core/planning_scene/include/moveit/planning_scene/planning_scene.h#L87) instance (i.e., `std::shared_ptr<planning_scene::PlanningScene>`), where that class is declared as,

```
class PlanningScene : private boost::noncopyable, public std::enable_shared_from_this<PlanningScene>
```

In the C++ `Foo` class I have,

```
std::shared_ptr<planning_scene::PlanningScene> Foo::GetPSPtr() {  // two different attempts shown
    // return ps_;
    return (*ps_).shared_from_this();
}
```

where `ps_` is a valid shared pointer to a PlanningScene instance created via `std::make_shared` in the `Foo` constructor.

Running some C++ integration tests works fine, where I pass a `foo_ptr` directly in C++ from `Foo` to `Baz`. But python integration tests (that use the bindings class) fail on `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What could be wrong here? I've dug around many SO questions on Boost Python segfaults, `enable_shared_from_this`, etc., but to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the Python interface requires a shared_ptr and not a raw pointer?

Comment: Good call @JiveDadson: According to [this Boost Python issue](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/29), it looks like Boost Python doesn't support C++ 11 std::shared_ptr, until v1.63.0. Unfortunately the `std::enable_shared_from_this` necessitates the use of `std::` rather than `boost::` shared pointer, and I'm stuck with boost v1.58.0 for compatibility w/ other packages in my project.

Comment: Use shared_ptr::get() to pass a raw pointer to Python?

Comment: What about something like a PIMPL pattern? Put the shared ptr into a struct, and add some forwarding methods.

Comment: Good suggestion @DanMašek, I was not familiar with the [PImpl pattern](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). In a hand-wavy way, the solution I just posted does this w/ `boost::bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use [`boost::bind`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) to generate a forwarding call wrapper around the method we're invoking from a Python-bindings class (i.e. `FooPython.GetPSPtr`):

```
void BazPython::RunThatFoo(const bp::object & foo) {
    FooPython & foo_obj = bp::extract<FooPython&>(foo);
    Baz::DoPSComputation(boost::bind(&Foo::GetPSPtr, &foo_obj)());
}
```